# JQuery Dialog does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I'm trying to implement a JQuery Dialog into my website to ask the user if he really wants to delete an Item.

But the following code does not work, it just does not show the dialog onclick. 
Here is my code:

The script

```
$(function() {
        $( "#delete" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false, 
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                DELETE: function() {$(this).dialog("close");},
                CANCEL: function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
            },
        });
        $( ".delete-action" ).click(function() {
            $( "#delete" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="delete" title="Delete" style="display: inline-block">
</div>
<button id="pass" class="delete-action"><img src="$base/includes/img/icons/16/trash.png" style="width: 16px; height: 16px;"/></button>
```

the includes + css

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"    rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- CSS -->
<style>
    .ui-widget-header,.ui-state-default, ui-button{
    background:#b9cd6d;
    border: 1px solid #b9cd6d;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
```

Here is a link to jsfiddle: [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/u2o5gn62/4/)

Can anyone provide a bit of help, because I don't know how to fix it :( I searched a lot on google and also here on StackOverflow, because there were many question similar to mine, but none of the solution worked for me

Thx for your help, the problem is solved and the provided code is up-to-date

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of your problem or not, but you'll need a comma separating each button: `DELETE: function() {$(this).dialog("close");},
                CANCEL: function() {$(this).dialog("close");}`

Comment: does not solve the problem :( but its sure wrong to not seperate them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should move your button outside of the div that is being used for creating the dialog

```
<div id="delete" title="Delete" style="display: inline-block">
</div>
<button class="delete-action">Open</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u2o5gn62/11/

Comment: it works in jsfiddle now :) but I seem to have something missing in my code to include jquery + ui properly. Is there something wrong with the included scripts ?

Comment: all the rest seems fine, whatever you're having should be a minor case. If you see some error in the console that you cant figure out, post an edit or a comment.

Comment: found the mistake, it was again the missing comma as mentioned by DeeMac. I seem to have it deleted while undoing some changes ;)